# Postgresql 9.5 alter table gets lock timeout without other long running queries

Tags: postgresql, locking, postgresql-9.5, alter

I was trying to execute `alter table mydb.r_group drop constraint test;` However it took more than 2 mins to get a exclusive lock. The table is busy table with many processes querying against it. (Processes use jdbc to access the db)

I tried to find a long running query using following query statement but couldn't find any except some with `idle` state.

```
SELECT
  pid,
  now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start AS duration,
  query,
  state
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE (now() - pg_stat_activity.query_start) > interval '5 minutes';
```

I also tried to find the query which is blocking the altering table query using following query statement but this query was also blocked so couldn't get the data.

```
SELECT blocked_locks.pid     AS blocked_pid,
         blocked_activity.usename  AS blocked_user,
         blocking_locks.pid     AS blocking_pid,
         blocking_activity.usename AS blocking_user,
         blocked_activity.query    AS blocked_statement,
         blocking_activity.query   AS current_statement_in_blocking_process
   FROM  pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocked_locks
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocked_activity  ON blocked_activity.pid = blocked_locks.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocking_locks 
        ON blocking_locks.locktype = blocked_locks.locktype
        AND blocking_locks.DATABASE IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.DATABASE
        AND blocking_locks.relation IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.relation
        AND blocking_locks.page IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.page
        AND blocking_locks.tuple IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.tuple
        AND blocking_locks.virtualxid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.virtualxid
        AND blocking_locks.transactionid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.transactionid
        AND blocking_locks.classid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.classid
        AND blocking_locks.objid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objid
        AND blocking_locks.objsubid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objsubid
        AND blocking_locks.pid != blocked_locks.pid

    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON blocking_activity.pid = blocking_locks.pid
   WHERE NOT blocked_locks.GRANTED;
```

Does anyone know what other steps I can take to find root cause?

Comment: Are you sure the state was just idle and not idle in transaction?

Comment: Yes. They are all idle not idle in transaction.

Comment: Maybe I was wrong. Some of them might be idle in transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try to find the object ID of the table in question:

```
SELECT tableoid
FROM mydb.r_group
LIMIT 1;
```

Then find all the locks on this table:

```
SELECT pid, mode, granted
FROM pg_locks
WHERE database = current_database()
  AND locktype = 'relation'
  AND relation = <the number from above>;
```

Then you have a list of all sessions that would block the `ALTER TABLE`.

Look for these `pid`s in `pg_stat_activity` to see what they are doing. Particularly interesting is `xact_start`, the time when the active transaction started.

If you cannot find the blocking process in `pg_stat_activity`, it could also be a background process, most likely an anti-wraparound autovacuum worker. Look for the blocking process ID using `ps` on the shell.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. I think I found pid holding shared access lock quite a long time. It was a big help.

Comment: Do you know how it is possible that the process is holding lock when there is no long running queries?

Comment: Yes: it started a transaction and never committed it. Locks are held until the end of the transaction.

Comment: However, I even could not find `idle in transaction` from pg_stat_activity table. They were all `idle`. I might make a mistake or there were timing issue when I query pg_stat_activity table?

Comment: I could be autovacuum, see my extended answer. If that is the case, do *not* interrupt it and let it finish.